# Не получается отправить файл на сервер с помощью cURL

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, curl, php7.2

```
$upload_url = "https://pu.vk.com/c815534/upload.php?act=add_audio&mid=305825127&aid=0&gid=0&hash=30b667141a2f3c0b826af655ed4f2979&rhash=9e188a1b6695caef703fe97e0fba3f45&api=1";

$musicaddress = realpath(__DIR__."\\music\\")."\\song.mp3";

$post = array (
'file' => curl_file_create ($musicaddress)
);

$ch = curl_init ($upload_url);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 
print_r($result);
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Здравствуйте. Что возвращает сервер?

Comment: Ошибка, выглядит так :(error:no_file)

Comment: Вы уверены, что путь до файла правильный?

Comment: что выводит var_dump($musicaddress) ? `__DIR__` у тебя от текущего php файла, а не от корня сайта, возможно поэтому неправильная путь к фалу указан.

Comment: "E:\Scripts\music\music.mp3"

Comment: ну так файл физически существует по этому пути?

Comment: Да, файл существует по этому пути

Comment: CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER посмотри (но тогда бы ошибку не выдавало бы вообще) тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15200632/how-to-upload-file-using-curl-with-php упоминается CURLOPT_SAFE_UPLOAD

Comment: А он должен быть равен FALSE?

Comment: Спасибо огромное, Jean-Claude
После установки параметра CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  на  FALSE всё заработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Со всеми сайтами, работающими по защищенному протоколу https, при условии что у вас нет необходимости проводить проверку SSL сертификата в целях безопасности, следует отключать проверку SSL сертификата опцией Curl:

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false);
```

Полная документация [на константы Curl](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php).